# Is it difficult to get study permit for Canada after a long academic gaps in between?

Tags: visas, canada

I come from Pakistan and residing in Saudi Arabia, I wanted to apply for bachelors degree program. Is it difficult to get study permit after a long.
Please note: i have strong financial statement and a good travel history visited ( UK, EUROPE AND US VISA IN PROCESSING)

Comment: Your question is attracting close votes as "off topic" probably because you want a long-term student visa, not a short-term visa for business or tourism. You may want to ask your question on [Expatriates.se]. Note that Canada usually wants applicants to have the entire first year's cost (tuition and living expenses) up front.